# Activity webview and Fragment Webview different behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, webview

I have a html page and i am downloading it in a webview, The problem is that it is loading in right way in Activity whereas in Fragments it has scrollbar (Please see the attached images)

Here is my code for Fragment Java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sem8subs, container, false);
        wvsem8 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.sem8web);
        wvsem8.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wvsem8.clearCache(true);
        wvsem8.clearHistory();
        wvsem8.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvsem8.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wvsem8.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wvsem8.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        getDataSem8S1();

        downloadsem8s1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sem8btn);

        // Capture button clicks
        downloadsem8s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                        "Downloading Soft Computing...", true);

                // Locate the class table named "ImageUpload" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "SemSubs8");

                // Locate the objectId from the class
                query.getInBackground("SasdsaHJac",
                        new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                            public void done(ParseObject object,
                                             ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                if (e == null) {
                                    hold8sub1 = object.getString("subData");

                                    saveDataSem8S1();
                                    getDataSem8S1();

                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }


                            }
                        });
            }

        });
        return v;
    }
```

Here is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sem8btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="download" />


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/sem8web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sem8btn" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong?

Please help

[image: Activity Webview]

[image: Fragment Webview]